# Trouble erasing items through list while iterating

Tags: c++

Okay, I have a STL list of references I am iterating through. This function has three equivalent parts. The function takes a wstring as a parameter, and runs the appropriate if statement. I have reduced the code to one if statement to try and get it working.

So, I check to see what has been passed in as an argument. I then check to see if the ClassItem is a certain type of animal. If it is, I check if it is hungry, and erase it from the list. I am just trying to avoid seg faults right now, and cannot seem to do it.

```
    list<ClassItem *>::iterator i = Items.begin();

    while(i != Items.end())    
    {
        if(!AnimalType.compare(L"tiger"))
        {
           if((*i)->IsAnimalType(L"tiger"))
           {
              if((*i)->IsHungry())
              {
                  i = Items.erase(i);

              }
           }
           else
           {
              ++i;
           }
        }
      // I have tried removing this
      else
      {
        i++;
      }
    }
```

I was under the impression that the current iterator is invalidated when I call erase. So, if I erase an element, I return the next valid iterator. Where am I going wrong?

EDIT: Thank you for all the quick help. The problem has been fixed. I have made use phresnel's solution and it worked wonderfully.

Comment: What happens if you have a `tiger` that is not hungry? Infinite loop, stack overflow, chaos...

Comment: what is AnimalType.compare(L"tiger")?

Comment: this code alone shouldn't segfault. please show complete example.

Comment: @erenon: I was just asking this myself. Probably the reason for the error we can only speculate about.

Comment: My apologies. Basically,  if(!AnimalType.compare(AnimalType)) would take a wstring AnimalType and run the correct if statement. In this case, I wanted to check if tigers where hungry, so I passed in L"tiger" into my function to run the appropriate if statement.

Comment: @Jonnywalkerr: That's a confusing design. Why not just `if (AnimalType == i->animal_type)`, and some better names. And of course: make sure to look into the _Replace typecode with polymorphism_-design pattern

Answer (score 3):

You are better off by using [std::list::remove_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove) with a suitable predicate. This avoids the manual loop entirely, reducing scope for errors, and helping to either remove or at least you localise the source of the problem, since you can rely on this idiom being correct as long as your predicate is.

```
bool badAnimal(ClassItem * item) 
{
  // return true if animal is to be removed 
 }

Items.remove_if(badAnimal);
```

Comment: @KarolyHorvath How is that?

Comment: because his code shouldn't segfault either. or to rephrase it: why do you think it would?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I don't really care about OP's code, but about what they are attempting to do.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath this should at least help OP to narrow down the place where the segfault could occur, and avoid unnecessary errors.

Comment: You see, if you've added all this information in the answer, it would have been completely fine, but because you didn't I think I posted perfectly valid comments. I was just trying to help. Really.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Yes, thanks, I appreciate that. I may extend the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I see no potential for a segfault here. Anyways:

---

There are (IMHO) two possible problems:

```
if(!AnimalType.compare(L"tiger"))
```

This looks fishy. What is `AnimalType`? Do you really expect the value of `if(!AnimalType.compare(L"tiger"))` to change during iteration, if `AnimalType` itself does *not*?

In any case, it looks like a read, therefore shouldn't write. It looks constant, therefore shouldn't change.

---

Then:

```
       if((*i)->IsAnimalType(L"tiger"))
       {
          if((*i)->IsHungry())
          {
              i = Items.erase(i);
          }
          // NO ITERATION IN CASE OF NOT HUNGRY.
          // ONCE TRAPPED HERE, YOU HAVE AN INFINITE LOOP,
          // EXCEPT AnimalType.compare(L"tiger") DOES SOMETHING
          // NON-SANE.
       }
       else
       {
          ++i;
       }
```

this should better be:

```
       if((*i)->IsAnimalType(L"tiger") && (*i)->IsHungry())
       {
          i = Items.erase(i);
       }
       else
       {
          ++i;
       }
```

However, even better would be to use the standard algorithms for element removal.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to add

```
continue;
```

after your erasion.

Comment: and then the problem is still there.

Comment: Why? After calling `erase()` there are no instructions left to execute inside the loop.

Comment: ... break is not needed if the OP wants to remove all hungry tigers from the list.